# Contour Attachments not being sent

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

This is my first go-round with Contour and I really like it!  I am stuck on one thing and hoping someone out there has some insight.

I have a simple 4 field form, nothing required, no rules...one of the fields is a file upload field.  It renders and works correctly on the form, but when I recieve the email with the form values, it does not include a link to the file, or a file attachment.  The attachment is also not shown in the "Entries" tab.  I tried installing Contrib which seems to have more support for attachments, but I still did not get any mention of the uploaded file in my email.

I am wondering if there is anything I have to do in the config, or similar to allow sending attachments.

I am running Umbraco v6.0.6 and Contour 3.0.14, Contrib is currently uninstalled.  I am adding the Razor Macro the page, not the UserControl.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here in case someone else runs up against this.

Out of desperation I decided to just start trying anything I could think of, so I tried adding the Contour form to my page as a UserControl (despite what I had read) instead of as a Macro, when I did that, I started receiving the attachment link text in my email so I re-installed Contrib and boom, attachments are on the email now.

SO, in summary, you need Contour (obviously), need the Contour Contrib package, and you need to add the macro as a user control and not as razor in order to send attachments